# Splitting string from [ as start character and ] as end character separated by comma into two lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, python-re

I have a input as  [1,3,4], [1,2,6,8] and I am new to using regular expression.
I want to split the above input into two parts as 1 3 4 and 1 2 6 8 and consider them as separate lists.
I have tried following but it is not working

````
pattern = re.compile(r'\[([^]]*)\]')
s=[1,3,4], [1,2,6,8]
print(pattern.findall(s))```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you need to use a regex? your input is already structured as a tuple of lists:

```
list_a, list_b = eval("[1,3,4], [1,2,6,8]")
print(list_a)
```

[1, 3, 4]

```
print(list_b)
```

[1, 2, 6, 8]

Comment: I would always go for this kind of simple solution. It can be done using regular expression but that's unnecessary for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `re.findall`, string `split()`, and a list comprehension:

```py
inp = "[1,3,4], [1,2,6,8]"
output = [x.split(',') for x in re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)*', inp)]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
[['1', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '6', '8']]
```